# How to get spotify user access token for Spotify Web API w/ FastAPI?

Tags: python, spotify, fastapi

Hi all I'm building out my own custom server for an iOS app that I've been developing which is meant to link to spotify for users can listen to their spotify songs. I'm using FastAPI to build out the server and am using Python 3.8. I'm also a novice with OAuth and HTTP routing. I'm aiming to have my MVP done in a month as the client side is finished.

With that being said here is the following route that I've wrote so far to get User Authorization:

```
@app.get("/login")
async def request():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        state = generate_random_string(16)
        params: dict = {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'response_type': 'code',
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
            'state': state
        }
        response = await client.get(
            SPOTIFY_URI + urlencode(params), 
            follow_redirects=True
        )
    print(type(response))
    return RedirectResponse(url='/callback')
```

So authorization successfully works, but I'm stuck on how to request access tokens for users. I have my redirect path as:

```
@app.get("/callback")
async def callback(
    code: Union[str, None] = Query(default=None), 
    state: Union[str, None] = Query(default=None)):
    return {'code': code, 'state' : state}
```

I followed the Spotify docs example but I'm stuck here as when it redirects, it doesn't show the access code and state which should be query parameters in the URI when the /authorize endpoint is called and redirected to my redirect URI. When I'm redirected to my /callback endpoint code and state are returned as null. I'm not sure as to why they are not being picked up by my route when the /authorize endpoint redirects to my /callback endpoint.

I know I need to make a POST request to the /api/token endpoint, in my redirect path, but this is where I'm stuck since I can't get the code and state variables in order to pass them as parameters for the POST endpoint.

Thank you all in advance for all your help.

Comment: You may set headers and use that in subsequent requests. Does Spotify api provide header based authentication?

Comment: @Irfanuddin it does! Problem is that the HTTPX library doesn't seem to allow you to pass headers in a redirect.

Comment: If you’re using HTTPX, you need to handle it yourself. You need get the redirect URL, make a new request with necessary headers.